# Delete from array (tableView) when Int value is 0

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I´m practicing my koding with trying to make a app thats keep track of the storage at my job.
I have a tableView that lists up a wide list of items. If we want to add toilet paper to the storage, I find the item in the tableView, then press the item (cell). I then use `prepareForSegue` to pass information to a new ViewController.
In the new ViewController I have a minusButton, a plusButton and a label. The label shows the name of the item, the pluss- and minusButton counts the amount of that item.
When the item amount is >= 1 it should display in a tableView.

Selection between the list of items available and the list of items that's in the storage is done in a tabBarContoller.

Code for the ViewController with available items:

```
class AvailableItemsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let itemsArray = ["Hand soap", "Hand towles", "Toilet paper", "Lightbulbs"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return itemsArray.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemsCell") as! AvailableItemsTableViewCell

cell.ItemsLabel.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



        let itemsSegueIdentifier = "ItemsSegue"

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == itemsSegueIdentifier
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ItemInfoViewController
            let itemIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

                if itemIndex == 0
                {
                    destination.itemName = "Hand soap"
                }
                if starterIndex == 1
                {
                    destination.itemName = "Hand towles"
                }
                if starterIndex == 2
                {
                   destination.itemName = "Toilet paper"
                }
                if starterIndex == 3
                {
                   destination.itemName = "Lightbulbs"
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

The next ViewController:

```
class ItemInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = Int()
    var itemName = String()


    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func plussBUtton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        counter += 1
        counterLabel.text = String (counter)

        if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController
        {
           tbc.totalArray.append("\(counter) pcs \(itemName))")

        }


    }
    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if counter != 0
        {
            counter -= 1
        }
        //Remove from totalArray
        let valueToCheck = itemName

        if let tbc = self.tabBarController as? CustomTabBarController
        {

           tbc.totalArray = tbc.totalArray.filter { $0 != valueToCheck }

        counterLabel.text = String (counter)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemLabel.text = itemName
        counterLabel.text = String (counter)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

I´m struggling to delete from the totalArray when the counter is 0.
The command `tbc.totalArray = tbc.totalArray.filter { $0 != valueToCheck }`works fine when I don't concatenate the `counter` and the `itemName`

So, how should I delete from the array when the counter hits 0?

Answer (score 0):

Since you append to the `totalArray` after increasing the counter you need too do it in the opposite order when removing otherwise the counter won't match. So first do the remove (filter) then decrease the counter.